# Screenflow video and speech in two separate steps

Tags: video, video-capture, audio-recording, voice-recording

Is it possible, with screenflow, record video and in a second time record speech while watching the previous screen capture ? I prefer to record my voice with a script and quietly :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, that's possible. just record your screen. Then in the ScreenFlow helper icon at the top of your screen, select "Add additional recording" and make your second pass with audio, as you're watching your original video

Comment: I, personally, prefer to use something like voice memo. Typically it happens I do mistakes while recording. In such a case I simply rewind the video to place where I did a mistake and pick up from there while voice memo records everything. Then, I simply split voice, cut mistakes and adjust the rest. This way, I have just one pass of voice recording.